# Gray colored text with answers

Tags: discussion, answers, voting

It came to my attention that some answers have the font in gray. What is the criteria for this? I am guessing that it might be low voting, but am not sure. The question with the same down voting is not in gray. Is there other places that can become gray?

[Who is the subject of Aにはaction?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3535)

Comment: I think gray out is only for answers with -3 or lower score.

Comment: @YOU I see. Thanks.

Comment: Is this a new feature? I never saw it before... Maybe it happens only in Beta SE, since on EL&U I never saw it.

Comment: @Alenanno: It is not new.  On some SE sites, graying is disabled ([probably by accident](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/837/answers-with-low-score-are-no-longer-shown-in-gray-text)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As YOU notes, this happens when the score of an answer drops to -3.

The gray text is intended to de-emphasize the answer somewhat, since most readers have clearly not found it particularly helpful thus far. At this point, if the author deletes it, he'll get the [peer-pressure badge](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/badges/38/peer-pressure).

Comment: Why do we have a badge for this kind of things?

Comment: @Pacerier, probably to encourage people to take down their answers if it's not helping anyone...